# Not required fields in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Can I have not required fields in my razor view ?

I have the below view, in which I want the hidden field as not mandatory field.
currently it is being treated as mandatory and my model state is false.

please adivse?

```
@using P.M.O
@model O

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Create a New O</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.C) 
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.C, new { @class = "txt"}) 
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Caption) 
    </div> <br />

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.N)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.N, new { @class = "txt"}) 
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.N)
    </div> <br />

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.D)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.D, new { @class = "txt"}) 
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.D)
    </div> 
    <br />
        @Html.HiddenFor(model=> model.P.Cr)
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</fieldset>
}
```

Model:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace P.M.O
{
[Serializable]
public partial class O
{
    /*** Construtor(s) ***/
    public O()
    {

    }

    public O(P obj)
        : this()
    {
        P= obj;
    }


    /*** Public Members ***/
    [Key, Display(Name = "Id")]
    public int PartyId { get; set; }


    /* IEntity */
    public string C{ get; set; }

    public string N{ get; set; }

    public string D{ get; set; }


    /* IAuditable */
    [NotMapped, ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public System.DateTimeOffset Created
    {
        get { return P.C; }
        set { P.C= value; }
    }

    /* Navigation Properties */
    /// <summary>
    /// Foreign key to Party: PartyId
    /// Organization is subtype of  Party
    /// </summary>
    public virtual P P{ get; set; }

}
}
```

Comment: Post your model as well please.

Comment: posted the model class..thanku

Comment: I assume that the `model.Party.Created` field is a `DateTime` field. If you want it to not be required you should be declaring it as a nullable `DateTime` field: `public DateTime? Created { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create childs or parent objects using Custom Model Binder. The model binder solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You should define your `Created` property as a nullable `DateTimeOffset`:

```
/* IAuditable */
[NotMapped, ScaffoldColumn(false)]
public System.DateTimeOffset? Created
{
    get { return Party.Created; }
    set { Party.Created = value; }
}
```

edit: and accommodating for the fact that the `Party` property might be `null`:

```
public System.DateTimeOffset? Created
{
    get 
    { 
        return Party == null ? null : Party.Created; 
    }
    set 
    { 
        if (Party == null) 
        {
            return; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            Party.Created = value; 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually a required field in database. We have a constraint on it to default it also we are handling in factory classes.Here my problem is Organization is child of Party. And some of the fields like Created are being referred from parent(pls see above model).When I am creating new organizations i will not have its associated Party and so my Organization model fails with null reference at Created property. To handle this I have added that hidden field in my view now it is being treated as mandatory, how to solve this?

Comment: Well, than your property needs to check to see if `Party` is `null`. I have added an alternative version that does this check. Could you see if it works?

Comment: getting conversion error between <null> and DateTimeOffset in get property :(

Comment: another problem with the property as above is - im getting the below exception: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in PartyBiz.dll, getting this exception at the check Party == null